# Converting WriteStream to TransformStream

Tags: node.js, stream, through2

I have a (somewhat weird) writable stream that I need to convert to a transform stream.

The writable stream, normally, sits at the end of a pipe chain and emits custom events once it has collected enough data for its output. I want it to go in the middle so I can pipe it to another writeStream, i.e:

```
    readStream.pipe(writeStreamToConvert).pipe(finalWriteStream);
```

What I done is the following and it works.

```
    const through2 = require('through2')


    var writeStreamToConvert = new WriteStreamToConvert();

    return through2.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {

        writeStreamToConvert.write(chunk)

        // object is the event emitted from the writestream
        writeStreamToConvert.on('object', (name, obj ) => {
            this.push(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + '\n')
        });            

        callback()
    })
```

This works fine, does not seem to leak memory and is fairly quick. However node gives me a warning:

```
Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 object listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

So I am a little bit curious if this is the correct way of converting writestreams?

Comment: Perhaps the event handler should be added in the object stream's constructor instead of the transform function. There is no way to have a constructor with `through2` though, so you'd have to do that directly using node's streams API. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks! I converted it to the stream API using _transform and now the Warning is gone. So putting the event handler in the constructor worked really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler would be best placed in a Transform stream constructor. Since `through2` does not support such initialization, you would need to use node's stream API directly.

Currently, a new event handler (which is never removed -- that is how `.on()` works) is being added for every object written to the `through2` stream. That is why the warning occurs.